# Problem with installing python package with ctypes based extension

Tags: python, ctypes

This is my package's directory:

```
mypack/
------- setup.py
------- mypack/
--------------- __init__.py
--------------- mypack.c
--------------- mypack.py
--------------- makefile
```

And this is my _ _ init _ _.py file:

```
from .mypack import *
```

My setup script is as below:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
mypack = Extension('mypack',
                    sources = ['mypack/mypack.c'])
setup(name='mypack',
      version='0.1.0',
      description='CTypes based package ...',
      ext_modules = [mypack], 
      packages=['mypack'],
  )
```

python3 setup.py build and python3 setup.py install are running successfully, but when importing the mypack there is an error:

```
OSError: no file with expected extension
```

I think python doesn't find the shared library file (mypack.so). Can anyone help me, please?

In mypack.py, I am loading the library as below:

```
libcd = npct.load_library("mypack", ".")
```

I got that when giving the path as "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages" instead of ".", the problem is solved. But I don't know the correct path in the user's OS will be the same as what I have mentioned, or not. How can I select the path correctly based on user's configurations?

Comment: Please post the *\_\_init\_\_.py* and *mypack.py* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Not a perfect solution, but this can solve my problem:

```
path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.absolute()
libcd = npct.load_library("mypack", str(path))
```